# Logging in on Windows device with a federated user

Tags: windows, azure, azure-active-directory, adfs, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a problem that's to do with Windows Devices and federated Azure users. We've built an application that uses the Graph API to provision Office 365 with users. These users are also saved in our on-prem active directory.

We've also built an application that provides SSO for these users. This application is compatible with handling multiple Office 365 tenants (through delegation)

So far, so good. We can provision without problems and SSO in the webflow works. For all this we use a custom STS on our side. The STS on it's turn uses our ADFS for authorization.

The problem we have is that when we use a Windows 10 device and try to login with a federated user, we always get the notification "Wrong username or password". We've triple checked the password, it's correct (remember the webflow works).

Through many hours of research, we concluded that we needed the WsFed as our authentication protocol. It seems that when you login with a device, the steps are as follows:

Give username -> Windows checks whether domain is federated -> the MetadataExchange URI is called -> the usernamemixed endpoint of our ADFS is called -> SOAP message gets sent to Office and you should be logged in.

We spent hours getting that to work, to no avail. We've now created a mirrored version of the MetadataExchange on a different URL and changed the location it will try to get the user from our ADFS. Calls go through there and everythings seems OK, but still we get the "wrong username or password" notification.

Using fiddler we can see that in one of the last steps Office returns the following error:

> "invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating
>   credentials. AADSTS50155: Device is not authenticated.

How do we get this to work. All device grants are applied on the Azure side (though it seems that AAD API and Graph API both have device grants, all of which we applied).

When we circumvent our own STS and link directly to the ADFS everthings works, this is however not desired because we need to have a solution that works with multiple tenants (also the reason we don't use AADSync).

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ECP endpoint is used, but that one only handles calls from Exchange clients (like iPhones, Outlook for Windows etc) and works like a charm. The windows login does not use that endpoint, so I don't think the solution can be found there. I suspect there are claims lost in translation when we use our own STS, but I can't find a source that tells me which claims are expected when dealing with a device.

Update: We were able to get the ADFS to work with multiple domains. By following tips from https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory/device-management-hybrid-azuread-joined-devices-setup we were able to translate claims so that multiple domains work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can post a schematic overview with the desired flow and the flow that does work?

Is the EPC-endpoint used in this flow? If so, is it hosted at the ADFS or in the Custom STS?